# Dynamically Average in Cell (Excel 2016)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have problem with dynamically average calcuation.

[image]

...after adding (I change Average manually)

[image]

In my Excel file I have users with some values and I'm every month adding new values and there is also Average that must increase. Now I edit this manually but I want to do that automatically. Is it possible? How should be the formula for this?

Note that I cannot move cells.

Comment: If I had to do it, I would insert the new column not in the end, but one before the end (in your case between D and E) and copy the values from the new F back to new E (which is quick with keyboard shortcurts). Then it would automatically resize the range passed to `average()`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all move the column with the average to a place where you don't need to move it anymore. Probably P column if you need to get all months in there.

Then in the P2 cell add this formula

```
=SUM(D2:O2)/COUNT(D2:O2)
```

This will first sum the range and then divide by the number of entries you have in the range.

However, this part: `also Average that must increase` is nothing that a formula can handle.
It will only calculate the average, sometimes it may increase and sometimes it will decrease.

Comment: They don't want me to move, so.. it must be like this.

Comment: @A.Flow OK. But just hide the cells that is not visible at the moment. Either use the hide or just set the cell width to 0 on the columns G:O (unused columns at the moment if P is the average)

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, you should move the average calculation else where.

Another approach is to create a named ranges.

For John, we will use following formula **for named range definition** and call it `JohnAvg`, this is generic formula for dynamic range, it will expand for the defined line automatically, considering you have only the months data you want to average there:

```
=$D$2:INDEX($2:$2;COUNTA($2:$2))
```

Then, the formula for calculating John's average is:

```
=AVERAGE(JohnAvg)
```

Comment: I can't move Average. It must be like it is. That's the theme they want. I just wanted to make it easier for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET(F2,0,4-COLUMN(),1,COLUMN()-4))
```

(Written to start in cell `F2`)

This will use `OFFSET` to create a Range that starts in Column 4 (D) and extends until the Column before the Cell that the formula is written in.